# Dynamic table name in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I am developing an application in Java that uses Hibernate to connect to MySQL database.

My application manages students of different batches. If a student joined in 2010 then they are in the 2010 batch, so whenever the administrators of the application create a new batch, my application has to create new tables for that batch. While the scheme is much more like the old tables that are already there in the database, the table name changes. How do I accomplish this using Hibernate?

How do I create the XML files and the classes required dynamically?

Comment: Check Pascal's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061846/hibernate-for-dynamic-table-creation)

Comment: Are you sure you want to create NEW TABLES? Copying tables when you add new data is just poor DB design. Rethink your design into a more relational DB approach ;)

Comment: This smells like a bad design. Why can't you make a table of batches and append a batch to a student for example.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot add a `BATCH_YEAR` column to the student table and query for certain on batches that way?

Comment: I would be adding about 2 to 3 tables each time a new batch arrives, one of these tables is a possible candidate of having 70,000 records or so and i would be having approximately 30 or more such batches, that is the prime reason i considered different tables for each batch...

Comment: DO not use differnt tables per batch. This way  will cause no end of performance problems, query problems and data integrity problems. You do not as a rule want to ever generate tables on the fly. And 70,000 X 30 is only about 2,100,000 records which is a tiny, tiny database table. Any database that is correctly indexed can easily handle that.

Comment: What could be the possible implementation in hibernate, if we decide to create tables on the fly.........???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your problem right, I think you want to check Hibernate Shards. Note that this is an advanced feature, unsupported and not really tested (nor maintained). So, use it at your own risk. You may want to pay special attention to the "Shard Selection Strategy" section:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/shards/reference/en/html_single/#shards-strategy-shardselection

From the documentation:

> We expect many applications will want to implement attribute-based sharding, so for our example application that stores weather reports let's shard reports by the continents on which the reports originate

But as the others said: think twice before splitting your data. Do it only if you expect really large volumes of data. A couple million records are not really that much.